# Matplotlib - Annotations of two separate scatter plots from dictionary

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations, scatter-plot

I am currently working with this data set from Our World in Data: https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.csv

I have created a code that allows me to plot two scatter plots of total mortality and total
case numbers per million on population density, all values are filtered by date (taking the log base 10 of population density):

```
scatter_countries_1 = {}

scatter_countries_1 = {
    'iso_code': data_filtered_by_date['iso_code'],
    'total_cases_per_million': data_filtered_by_date['total_cases_per_million'],
    'total_deaths_per_million': data_filtered_by_date['total_deaths_per_million'],
    'population_density':np.log10(data_filtered_by_date['population_density'])
}

plt.figure(figsize=(25,15))

# Scatter 1 - Total cases (per million) on population density (log 10)
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.scatter(scatter_countries_1['population_density'], scatter_countries_1['total_cases_per_million'], color = 'blue')
plt.xlabel('Population density (logbase 10)', fontsize = 15)
plt.ylabel('Total cases (per million)', fontsize = 15)
plt.title('Scatter chart - Total cases (per million) on population density (logbase 10)', fontsize = 20)

# Scatter 2 - Total mortality (per million) on population density (log 10)
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.scatter(scatter_countries_1['population_density'], scatter_countries_1['total_deaths_per_million'], color = 'red')
plt.xlabel('Population density (logbase 10)', fontsize = 15)
plt.ylabel('Total mortality (per million)', fontsize = 15)
plt.title('Scatter chart - Total mortality (per million) on population density (logbase 10)', fontsize = 20)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

However, I am having trouble annotating the plots with their corresponding iso codes. I know to use `plt.annotate` but I am unsure how to use it in this instance when i have two scatter plots and it is in a dictionary. Hopefully someone can help out and lead in down the right direction, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use `plt.subplots` and a for loop with `zip`:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(5,10))

for ax, yname, color in zip(axes, ['total_cases_per_million', 'total_deaths_per_million'], ['red' , 'blue']):
    x = scatter_countries_1['population_density']
    y = scatter_countries_1[yname]
    ax.scatter(x, y, color = color)
    ax.annotate(scatter_countries_1['iso_code'], xy=(x,y))
```